# Ellipsis (…) with Jquery/JavaScript/CSS with support for IE 8 and ability to work on Grid/HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ellipsis

I want to implement ellipsis (…) functionality on my [Jquery DataTable](http://www.datatables.net/). I googled around and found tons of [examples](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=elipise&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=6MIjVJLWFc6AuAS96oCACw#rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&q=ellipsis%20jquery).

I really likes this [Jquery Plugin](http://jrvis.com/trunk8/)

**My requirements:**

1. Support for IE 8
2. Should be able to work on JQuery DataTable or any HTML table
3. Simple solution. Does not matter if solution uses Jquery/JavaScript or CSS
4. I would like the ability to see the hidden text. so if user clicks on `...` or `read more` option, he must see the full text. see this [example](http://jrvis.com/trunk8/#toggle)
5. Text width should adjust based on column type. So if I am showing names which can be 100 character long in a column, ellipsis should come after 40-50 character and if the column size is 20 character, I should be able to configure column to show ellipsis after 10 character.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: @Teemu: How can i implement Ellipsis satisfying all the requirement.

Comment: Well you can [cut it off with ellipsis with just CSS](http://jsbin.com/qecuw/1/edit)